# Hybridizing AngularJS and Angular with the Angular CLI. Import error with the example code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

The project I'm on is finally getting around to transitioning from AngularJS to Angular, and we're going to be hopping right to Angular 12 with the Angular CLI. I've been trying to pilot this by running through Angular's own [PhoneCat upgrade tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#phonecat-upgrade-tutorial). The problem is this seems to have been written with an older version of Angular in mind, and attempting to follow this with Angular 12 and the Angular CLI is a hard stop.

I did eventually get it running through the "Bootstrapping a hybrid PhoneCat" section (i.e. I run `ng serve` and PhoneCat runs fine). It turns out the missing step was to update `angular.json`'s "scripts" property with a file list:

```
"scripts": [
      "src/app/app.module.ajs.ts",
      "src/app/app.config.ts",
      ...
]
```

With that running, I continued on with the transition guide and updated the `phone.service.ts` and `app.module.ts` with the exact code listed in the [Upgrading the Phone Service](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-the-phone-service) section, along with the changes to `phone-list.component.ts` and `phone-detail.component.ts` in order to use the new `phone.service.ts`. I pulled a direct copy/paste from those files, so it probably doesn't have a typo. Since I was now pulling into the Angular app with the Provide statement in `app.module.ts` I also removed it from the `angular.json` scripts array, which I imagine is equivalent to the tutorial's instruction of removing it from the script tags.

When I run `ng serve` now, I only get the following error:

`Cannot use import statement outside a module`, failing on the line `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';` which is the very first line of `phone.service.ts`. I've tried adding it back into `angular.json`, tried adding it into `tsconfig.app.json`, tried swapping the `tsconfig.json`'s "module" from `"es2020"` to `"commonjs"`, set the "target" to `"es2015"`, the "type" to `"module"` in `package.json`... Same error, 100% of the time. Funnily enough if I put the `import` statement AFTER `declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;` I simply get the error `unexpected token var`.

What can I try next?

Comment: Thomas, do you still need help with this old question?

Comment: (Minor writing tip: for `inline formatting` you only need single backticks. Triples are required for block formatting).